# Using svg symbols for styling elements in ms4w (mapserver)?

Tags: postgis, mapserver, svg, ms4w

I have MapServer installed in a windows machine. I have imported into my PostGIS db osm data and want to style certain elements (nodes) with svg symbols.

The problem is that the version of MapServer that I have (I am using ms4w) does not have precompiled the libsvg-cairo library which is needed in order to use SVG symbols for styling elements.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can contact MS4W support and discuss with them the possibility of having them compile a version of MapServer that has the libsvg-cairo library compiled for you.  You can compile MapServer yourself with this support, or you can use a MapServer binary from [GISinternals](http://www.gisinternals.com/).  There might be other Windows MapServer binaries that have this support.